# Does the word "non-companies" exist? Is it usual?

Tags: compounds

I'm seeing some results on Google but it seems quite an unusual word combination.

Is it okay to use it or would it be considered "weird"?

Context:

> ##### Free for non-companies
>
> We believe Open Source should be free for individuals and non-profits. Only companies pay.

The word "non-profit" isn't usable as it wouldn't convey the same message.

Comment: In the absence of any context, sources, or examples, I am voting to close this question.

Comment: Makes sense, thanks. I edited the question and added the context.

Comment: In the business world, we typically use the term "unincorporated concerns/businesses."

Comment: Unincorporated and not-for-profit are not the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/noncompany) lists the corresponding premodifier usage (as the closed compound), but labels it an adjective:

> **noncompany** [adjective] (not comparable)
>
> Not of or relating to a company (business enterprise).

A credible example is from the information put out by the [UK Government's Charity Commission for England and Wales](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/charity-reporting-and-accounting-the-essentials-cc15b/charity-reporting-and-accounting-the-essentials):

> *Accruals*
>
> Non-company charities with gross income of over £250,000 during the
> financial year, and all charitable companies must prepare their
> accounts on the accruals basis in accordance with the SORP.

But there seem to be few examples on the internet of non-attributive usage. One is:

> Consensys, a 'non-company' with a mission

[[Usbek & Rica](https://usbeketrica.com/fr/article/consensys-a-non-company-with-a-mission-use-ethereum-to-change-the-world)]

And another:

> Additionally, if the limited company is in an LLP with a non-company
> such as an individual, then those non-company partners will not get
> any relief.

[[Empowerrd](https://www.empowerrd.com/guide/can-an-llp-claim-rd-tax-credits/)]

And one from the [UK] [Law Office](https://www.lawcom.gov.uk/app/uploads/2015/03/cp164_Company_Security_Interests_Consultation.pdf):

> This would be a non-company selling to a non-company, but concerning
> one security interest that was registrable in the Company Charges
> Register

Here is an example of the plural form:

> [P]lease list all responsible names for non-companies including
> trading as business name

[[Tameside MBC; Gtr Manchester](https://www.tameside.gov.uk/TamesideMBC/media/foi/sbrapp.pdf)]

But the fact that some obviously feel the need to support the unusual usage with scare-quotes shows that the practice is uncommon. And in fact only a few percent of the alleged 49 000 hits in a Google search for << "a non-company" -charity >> use the string non-attributively.

I'd advise the inclusion of scare quotes at the moment if the need to use the noun non-attributively is genuine. As is often the case, in ten years the scare quotes could be seen as no longer optimal.

Answer (score 3):

> Does the word "non-companies" exist?

To set aside the contentious and metaphysical point of "What is a word?", you could rephrase the question as "**Does 'non-company' exist as a term in current Modern English? And if so, what currency and meaning does it have?**"

The problem with words prefaced by "non-" is that they are negations of some aspect of the word that follows. Negation as a descriptor is rarely satisfactory where there are a number of alternatives available:

"The creature is a non-mammal" is unhelpful as there are several other categories (real and imaginary) of creature that it could be.

Compare:

A: "What did he look like?"
B: "He looked like a non-lamppost."

In your example, you disregard commercial enterprises that are not companies *in the legal meaning of the word*, and it is therefore difficult to see what "non-company" is intended to restrict.

If you mean "**non-commercial**", then the problem is solved by using that common word.